# KeyError: 'Date' when using DataReader at Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, keyerror

I have a specific case in which i get an KeyError, that seemed to me not yet solved at Stackoverflow.

Here is the Code that i use

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

portfolio = ["FB", "AMZN", "APPL", "NFLX", "GOOG" ]

start = "2018-01-01"
end = "2020-01-01"


df = pd.DataFrame()

for asset in portfolio:
    df[asset] = web.DataReader(asset, data_source = "yahoo", start = start, end = end)["Adj Close"]

df
```

and here is the Error Message

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-cb7c572224e0> in <module>
     13 
     14 for asset in portfolio:
---> 15     df[asset] = web.DataReader(asset, data_source = "yahoo", start = start, end = end)["Adj Close"]
     16 
     17 df

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    212                 else:
    213                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 214             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    215 
    216         return cast(F, wrapper)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    376             retry_count=retry_count,
    377             pause=pause,
--> 378             session=session,
    379         ).read()
    380 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in read(self)
    251         # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252         if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253             df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254         # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255         elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    159         prices = DataFrame(data["prices"])
    160         prices.columns = [col.capitalize() for col in prices.columns]
--> 161         prices["Date"] = to_datetime(to_datetime(prices["Date"], unit="s").dt.date)
    162 
    163         if "Data" in prices.columns:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'
```

what am i doing wrong here?

It seems like he programmed lines are very simple and i assume that the issue is not in here.
Other solutions that were presented at Stackoverflow seemed to be very specific too, so that i cannot really derive from that.

Thanks guys, i appreciate!

Benjamin